# Why is this java code not saving data in database?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, database-connectivity

```
try{
     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

     try{
            try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/crm","root","")) {
                PreparedStatement pstmt=con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO user_tbl (email, password, role) VALUES (?,?,?) ");

                pstmt.setString(1,"amandhakal79@gmail.com");
                pstmt.setString(2,"amandhakal79@gmail.com");
                pstmt.setString(3,"Engineer");

                int z=pstmt.executeUpdate();

                }
            } catch(SQLException exception1) {
                System.out.println("Caught an exception "+exception1);
            }
      } catch(ClassNotFoundException | IllegalAccessException | InstantiationException e) {
          System.out.println("No driver found "+e);
    }
```

Everything is ok in database.
i.e. there is database as well as table with same columns. But, this code is not working. What may be the problem?

Comment: did you forget to set the 3rd PreparedStatement parameter?

Comment: You have `pstmt.setString(2` twice and no `pstmt.setString(3`

Comment: The third parameter is marked as the second, too... Have you tried `pstmt.setString(3,"Engineer");`?

Comment: Remove `con.close();` as that will be done for you, _after_ the automatic `pstmt.close()`.

Comment: I corrected that too; but it didn't work.

Comment: any errors in the console?

Comment: there is no error in the console

Comment: What JDDC and Mysql versions are you usung?

Comment: Did you verify the [Connection's] autocommit setting ?

Comment: you have errors in your code with extra bracket `}` and missing `catch` syntax. you should try to clean your code and downsize to one `try/catch` with generic `Exception`.